# Bibliography and big Table are intersecting in IEEEtran template

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I am trying to fit a double column table in IEEEtran format but the underlying issue is that the bibliography is intersecting the table like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]  % t to make it on top
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.2}
\parbox{\textwidth}{\caption{Comparison between the EWQEWWQEWQE and HTHQGDQWE}}
\label{tab:table1}
\setlength\doublerulesep{1.5pt}% <-- set distance between double rule

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tabular}{c||c c c c c}
\hline
\textbf{AA} & \textbf{BBB}       & \textbf{CCC}   & \textbf{DDD}                                                           & \textbf{Capacitance vs. Voltage/State} & \textbf{EEEE}          \\ \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{FFFF}  & 43$\degree$                        & 4$\degree$                          
& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}ABCDEFGH; \\[-0.3cm] EFGHIJKL\end{tabular} & ABCDEFGH                            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}WACFWD \\[-0.3cm] KGWHWRQW \end{tabular}                           \\ 
\textbf{QJSHGEQ}       & ABCDEFHW                         & ABCEDHWAW                         & ABCEDHWAWR                                                         & ABCDHEWAW                                & ABCDEHWQ               \\ \hhline{=#=====}
\textbf{ABCDEWQ} & \textbf{ABCDWAHW} & \textbf{ABCDWAWE} & \textbf{ABDWQ EWQ}                                                                 & \textbf{Control}                       & \textbf{ABCDWH QWE} \\ \Xhline{1pt}
\textbf{ABCDHWQWE}  & ABEWHQWE                & QBWEHQWEHWQ    & WQBEWQWE                                                                          & JQWEDEQ               & BWEQWEQ             \\ 
\textbf{EWQEDTC}       & VJWEQWEWQWE                  & HEWQWEDFWQ     & JEWQWESQER                                                                           & EWQWEEWQWE              & JEWQWE EWQWE             \\ 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The table is located at the top of the page and the bibtex begins on the left column below this table and continues on the right column but as you can see it starts at the right column from the top.

I made several attempts to fix this:

Attempt 1: Place `\begin{table*}` instead of `\begin{table}` but this made the table completely vanish from its position and reappears at the end of the document.

Attempt 2: Place multicols on the reference, this forced the references to be in double column format on the left format like this:

[image]

The two columns above are both located entirely on the left column (multicols should seperate one column to left and one column to right but in my case it generated two columns and placed them in the left column).

I would hope for some assistance or suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what "but this made the table completely vanish from the pdf" entails. E.g., does the table show up at the very end of the document?

Comment: Hello, Indeed the table vanishes from its position and reappears on an extra page at the very end of the document @Mico

Comment: In fact, it literally vanishes from the document if I use float H instead of t @Mico

Comment: You should definitely not use any positioning specifiers with `table*` environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If I correctly understood your problem, your table width require that it span both document columns. For this you need to replace `table` with `table*`.
  -Code for table is unnecessary complex. For example, instead nested tables you ca use `\makecell` command defined in the package of the same name and use rules from `booktabs` instead `\hhlines` (both packages you load in document preamble}.
- That `table*` can appear on the same page where it is insert in text, load package `stfloats`.
- Using `tabularray` package for table make code more concide:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[t]
    \centering
\caption{Comparison between the EWQEWWQEWQE and HTHQGDQWE}
\label{tab:table1}
%
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[l, font=\bfseries] | *{5}{X[l]} @{}},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries, m},
              rowsep = 3pt
             } 
    \toprule
AA      &   BBB &   CCC &   DDD &   Capacitance vs. Voltage/State
                                        &   EEEE                \\ 
    \midrule
FFFF    & \qty{43}{\degree}                        
                & \qty{4}{\degree}
                        & ABCDEFGH;  EFGHIJKL
                                & ABCDEFGH
                                        & WACFWD KGWHWRQW   \\
QJSHGEQ & ABCDEFHW 
                & ABCEDHWAW 
                        & ABCEDHWAWR 
                                & ABCDHEWAW
                                        & ABCDEHWQ               \\ 
        \midrule
\SetRow{font=\bfseries}
ABCDEWQ & ABCDWAHW
                & ABCDWAWE
                        & ABDWQ EWQ 
                                & Control
                                        & ABCDWH QWE            \\ 
        \midrule
ABCDHWQWE   
    & ABEWHQWE  & QBWEHQWEHWQ 
                        & WQBEWQWE
                                & JQWEDEQ
                                        & BWEQWEQ               \\
EWQEDTC & VJWEQWEWQWE
                & HEWQWEDFWQ     
                        & JEWQWESQER
                                & EWQWEEWQWE              
                                        & JEWQWE EWQWE          \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer, that cells contents are centered (and not left align, what is to my taste nice), you need in column specification replace `l` with `c`.